# Elasticsearch TransportError(400, u'parse_exception', u'Failed to derive xcontent')

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to add a new field to an existing document in elasticsearch. I use the elasticsearch python API to do this.
My query is :

```
addField = { "script" : { "inline" : "ctx._source.langTranslation = test"}}
esclient.bulk(body = addField)
```

When I try this I get this error :
[image]

I search how to avoid this error but not found anything. What is wrong with my resquest ?

Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, instead of use bulk function I use update function :

```
esclient.update(index = hit['_index'], doc_type = hit['_type'], id = hit['_id'], body = {"doc": {"langTranslation": translation}})
```

And it works, I don't have any error message.